# ESLint RC rule not working, while rule comment works and other rules do

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, eslint, eslintrc

When I use this comment with the following code, it reformats the code:

```
/*eslint object-property-newline: "error"*/
const obj1 = { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', baz: 'baz' };
```

However, when I add this line to my ESLint RC file instead, it doesn't reformat, while other rules seems to apply.

```
rules: {
    'object-property-newline': 'error', 
    'other rules': 'warn',
    // ...
}
```

Does anyone have an idea?

**Edit - For example, this rule does apply:**

```
'object-curly-newline': ["error", "always"],
```

If I add this code:

```
var x = { xs: 1, xy: 2, greg: 3 };
```

And save the file, it changes to:

```
const x = {
  xs: 1, xy: 2, greg: 3,
};
```

But I want every object property on a new line, which I hope to achieve with `'object-property-newline': 'error',`.

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-property-newline

Comment: Are you sure that correct eslint file is being applied?

Comment: @RaviKumarGupta I'm not sure, the file is called `.eslintrc.js`

Comment: But ESLint reloads when I save the file

Comment: Will you be able to share full elint file? If you're using typescript should you not be using the tslint.json file?

Comment: @RaviKumarGupta I added the file. It seems to be loaded correctly, but this rule doesn't apply somehow. For example this one: `'object-curly-newline': ["error", "always"],`, like I added to the edit

Comment: @RaviKumarGupta I figured it out, thank you! See my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that adding `allowAllPropertiesOnSameLine` and setting it to `false` is necessary, even though I thought that would be the default option.

```
'object-property-newline': ["error", { "allowAllPropertiesOnSameLine": false }],
```